# How to prove that $\det(A^TA+B^TB) \geq 0$ for $A,B $ real matrices?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant, symmetric-matrices, positive-semidefinite

If $A,B \in M_n(\mathbb{R})$, how can I prove that $\det\left(A^TA+B^TB\right)\ge0$? Any hint would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Hint: $A^TA$ is positive semi-definite.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You first show that the sum of positive semi-definite is positive semi-definite, and then that the determinant of positive semi-definite is non-negative.